# Adding glowy effect to an image

Tags: python, ruby, image-processing, imagemagick

I would like to permanently add a glow effect to a bunch of images. preferably using either Ruby or Python (open to other ideas as well).

Example of what I'm looking to do (see top half):
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be as simple as using imagemagick or gd to composite a PNG with transparency on top of your target image. Imagemagick's command line [Composite](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php) tool will get you there quite painlessly.

If you're displaying these on a webpage, though, I'd recommend that you just use `position: absolute` to overlay a glow image on top of the images. That way, you don't have to modify your source images, and can easily adjust or remove the glow effect as desired.

Comment: Or RMagick in Ruby or PythonMagick for Python.

Comment: I initially was using the overlay glow for images via css however, i use enhanced tool-tips about the image and the top half doesn't show the tool-tip due to the overlay.

Anyways, your suggestion is viable and I am already testing this out now. Thanks!